# Emplace object derived from non-copyable into vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, move-semantics, emplace

I have objects that holds pointers and shares them with others. Moving them is fine, but copying not. I would like to store them in vectors and maps. The following code works **only** when `A` has no destructor. However I would need a destructor to clean up my pointers.

```
#include <vector>

struct OnlyMove
{
    OnlyMove(const OnlyMove&) = delete;
    OnlyMove& operator=(const OnlyMove&) = delete;
    OnlyMove(OnlyMove&&) = default;
    OnlyMove& operator=(OnlyMove&&) = default;

protected:
    OnlyMove() = default;
};

struct A : OnlyMove
{
    A(int){}
    ~A(){} // makes compilation fail
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> y;
    y.emplace_back(1);
}
```

The error when I *have* a destructor:

> /usr/local/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = A; _Args = {A}]':
>   …
>   error: use of deleted function 'OnlyMove::OnlyMove(const OnlyMove&)'

I don't understand why. What role does the destructor play here?

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64d31f5b000f4bcc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
struct A : OnlyMove
{
    A(int){}
    A(A&&) = default;  // need this
    ~A() {} 
};
```

When you introduce the desctructor, the move constructor disappears. Without the move constructor or a copy constructor, it can't be placed in a vector.

EDIT: the move constructor is best if it is `noexcept`, otherwise `std::vector::resize` and `std::vector::push_back` have no guarantees when exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but had other problems in my code, and in the example code I didn't think about it anymore.

Comment: I also realized that I can save myself all the trouble by using unique_ptrs.

Comment: @ypnos that will also work, since unique_ptrs are already movable. Note however, that if this is performance critical code, then the extra memory management might affect performance